# PHP Displaying current month in option select

Tags: php

How to make the current month selected by default in option select using php

Here is what i have tried so far.

```
$curmonth = date("F");
```

And to display the entire month

```
<select>
<?php
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
$allmonth = date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")))
?>
 <option value="<?php 
   echo $i; 
   if($curmonth==$allmonth)
   {
   echo 'selected';
   }
   ?>" 
   >
    <?php
    echo date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")));

    }
    ?>
    </option>
```

And according to the above code, I am assigning the current month as $curmonth, and inside loop assigning the $allmonth for entire, month.

And inside the `Value`

```
<option value="<?php 
   echo $i; 
   if($curmonth==$allmonth)
   {
   echo 'selected';
   }
   ?>" 
   >
    <?php
    echo date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")));

    }
    ?>
    </option>
```

for checking if the current month equals all month and displaying the `selected` to make it select. But i am not getting result.. What i am getting is all the items are being displayed in the option select.

What i am missing ?

Comment: Look at the part where you check if the month is "this month". You're not ending the quoting for `value`. Missing `"` before you print `select`.

Answer (score 2):

What you have missed is,

You are trying to display the selected inside the **value**

What you need to do is

```
<option value="<?php 
echo $i; 
?>"
<?php
if($allmonth==$curmonth)
{
  echo ' selected';
}
?>     
>
<?php
echo $allmonth;
}
?>
</option>
```

So, the result will be

```
<select >
<option value="1">
January<option value="2">
February<option value="3">
March<option value="4">
April<option value="5">
May<option value="6">
June<option value="7">
July<option value="8">
August<option value="9" selected>
September<option value="10">
October<option value="11">
November<option value="12">
December</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not correctly closing the `<option>` tags you are creating. Indenting you're code makes these issues more apparent:

```
<select>
<?php
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
    $allmonth = date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")))
    ?>
    <option value="<?php 
    echo $i; 
    if($curmonth==$allmonth)
    {
        echo 'selected';
    }
    ?>" 
    >
    <?php
    echo date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")));
    //Close tag inside loop
    ?>
    </option>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are wrong here

```
    <option value="<?php 
       echo $i; ?>"
<?php 
       if($curmonth==$allmonth)
       {
       echo 'selected';
       }
       ?>" 
       >
        <?php
        echo date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")));

        }
        ?>
        </option>
```

You have missed closing quotes for the value

Answer (score 0):

You have error with closing quotes in the value of options in the line

```
   <option value="<?php 
   echo $i; if($curmonth==$allmonth)
   {
   echo 'selected';
   }
   ?>" 
     ^ // This is the quotes opened for value and is not properly closed
   >
```

Here you have to close the quotes. As per your code it will display as:

```
 <option value="9 selected" >
```

Also you are not closing `<option>` properly. Change your code to :

```
<select>
<?php
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
   $allmonth = date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")))
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if($curmonth==$allmonth){echo 'selected';}?> >
                                  ^  // close quotes here
   <?php
   echo $allmonth;?>
   </option>
}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this example:

```
$current = date('F');
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $month = date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")));
    if( $current == $month )
        echo  $month . " - Selected \r\n";
    else 
        echo $month . "\r\n";
}
```

**IN HTML FORMAT:**

```
echo "<select>";
$current = date('F');
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $month = date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")));
    if( $current == $month )
        echo "<option value='$month' selected='selected'>"  $month . "</option>";
    else 
        echo "<option value='$month'>"  $month . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://codepad.org/AqHUITGD)</kbd>